# use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserNotificationSettings'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am trying to compile an existing application using Xcode 6.

This is my code:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIApplication.sharedApplication currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

This is my error:

```
use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserNotificationSettings'
```

I do not know how to resolve this issue.

Here is my check for iOS 8:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(_iOS_8_0)) {

        // Displaying notifications and ringing

        if ([self isMissingMandatoryNotificationTypes:[UIApplication.sharedApplication enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]]) {

            [self registrationWithSuccess:^{
                DDLogInfo(@"Push notifications were succesfully re-enabled");
            } failure:^{
                [self.missingPermissionsAlertView show];
            }];
        }

    } else {

        // UIUserNotificationsSettings
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIApplication.sharedApplication currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

Comment: Is your app for iOS8 ?

Comment: Have you changed your deployment target?

Answer (score 9):

make it this way:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 80000

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIApplication.sharedApplication currentUserNotificationSettings];

#endif
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.

Comment: for me this didn't work using xcode 5.1.1 and iphone with version 8.1.1